# "Have always been" vs "was always"

Tags: grammar

Can anyone please tell me what's the difference between "**have always been**" and "**was always**" in the following sentence is And which one is correct? Can they both be used interchangeably in the following context?

- I ***have always been/was always*** a been a fan of spanish football but from today I won't support the spanish international team as they are not playing well.

Comment: In this context there's really no difference.  *"Have always been"* implies "up to this moment", while *"was always"* means that you were, but are not now.   With the past tense by itself, it's not clear when you changed your mind, but since you say *"from today"* there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Ey, keep supporting the Spanish team! They haven't played the first match yet ;-P

Comment: I had always been a fan of Spanish football but from today...